# Handling Asynchronous API Call in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using Jmeter for functional Testing, below is a problem that I am facing and need some help/suggestion on how to overcome that.

I have a thread-group that consists of 2 requests, 1st is API call and 2nd is sending message to Active MQ.

Now the flow is that I need to do first the API call (this will wait for response), then send the message to a particular Active MQ queue and then only I will get the response for the API.

But since jmeter does sequential execution of requests, its get stuck at the API call waiting for the reply and never executes the second part.

I worked on the below solution but even that did not help.

1 Use a parallel controller and put both the API and ACtive MQ call under the same.
2 Add a Timer to the Active MQ call, so that it just did after the API call (2 Sec)

But when I checked in details I see that both the requests are sent at the same time and the timer does not come into effect anywhere.

Any way I can handle this scenario?

Please note I will get a response to the API only when I send message to the particular Active MQ Queue, else it will timeout in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your Parallel Controller approach will work, however you need to amend the configuration a little bit, something like:

   [image]
2. You could put your ActiveMQ Request under a different Thread Group and use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) for synchronization between threads
3. You can keep the current setup but replace the JMS Sampler with the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)  and send the message to ActiveMQ programmatically:

   [image]

   Textual code representation for your convenicence:

   ```
   sleep(2000)
   def connectionFactory = new org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory('your activemq URL')
   def connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
   connection.start()
   def session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
   def destination = session.createQueue('your queue name')
   def producer = session.createProducer(destination)
   def message = session.createTextMessage('your message body')
   producer.send(message)
   connection.close()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [while controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller). It will keep on executing till the desired outcome then the next request will be executed.

Hope this helps.

Update:-
While Loop controller execute its samplers until the condition specified is not set to **False**. The condition can be any variable or function that eventually evaluates to the string 'false'.

So, you need to specify a variable or function in While Loop, that has value 'true' and becomes 'false' somewhere else in the script. Once it changes to 'false', JMeter will exit the While loop.

For example if you are using a X-Path extractor in your script which have a variable named Status and its value changes from 'Start' to 'Finish' during the execution and you want to execute your script till 'Finish' has not been met, then you can use the expression **${__javaScript("'${imp_Status}'!='finish'",)}** in your While loop and it will execute the samplers under While controller till the status = finish is met.

It is sort of polling based on certain condition. In your first API reponse, consider one value to be appear as the condition upon which first api call is successful.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this approach , a little more details please.

Answer (score 0):

For your Problem statement, following design will work.

- Use 2 Thread Groups, add API call to first Thread group and Message to Active MQ call to second Thread Group
- Add a delay to second Thread Group so that it should not run before first Thread Group
- Run Test Plan

[image]
[image]

Comment: I want them to be part of 1 thread group , i am using jmeter as a function tool where we are representing 1 thread group as 1 TC , and all the samplers / assertion that are present in that thread group can be consider as test steps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you just need to define [timeout for HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request),

If you define Response Timeout as 60000 (milliseconds), and it will only wait for a minute and then continue to next request

> Connect Timeout Connection Timeout. Number of milliseconds to wait for a connection to open. No
>
> Response Timeout Response Timeout. Number of milliseconds to wait for a response. Note that this applies to each wait for a response. If the server response is sent in several chunks, the overall elapsed time may be longer than the timeout.

Comment: No , i need to send the second request (Message to Active MQ) while the first request is still under execution.